# What is the value of creating a viewmodel as DataContext vs as a StaticResource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datacontext

In [this WPF tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/819294/wpf-mvvm-step-by-step-basics-to-advance-level) in level 2, the author creates the viewModel in `Window.Resources` like so:

```
<Window.Resource>
    <local:myViewModel x:Key="viewmodel"/>
</Window.Resource>
```

and binds each value with `{Binding myValue, Source={StaticResource myViewModel}}`, however other similar tutorials sets `Window.DataContext` to the viewModel like so:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:myViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

then simply binds values using `{Binding myValue}`.

**My question is:** Is there an appreciable difference between them, or is this a user preference?

Comment: user preference. you could also bind the datacontext to the resource. `DataContext={StaticResource viewmodel}`

Comment: I use neither, I always use `this.DataContext = new MainViewModel()` in MainWindow's constructor.

Comment: Convention. The latter is the more "correct" method. The former is generally used for other purposes, so whilst you can do it, it would be odd to do so.

Answer (score 2):

There is a semantic difference.

- If multiple controls reference the static resource, they all refer to the same object.
- If you set the `DataContext` of your UI elements to an instance of your model class, each element gets its own instance.

To illustrate, consider this model class:

```
public class Model
{
    private static int counter;

    private readonly int id;

    public Model()
    {
        id = counter++;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return id.ToString();
    }
}
```

...and some XAML snippets that use it:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <wpf:Model x:Key="ModelResource"/>
</Window.Resources>
...
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="20" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Content="{StaticResource ModelResource}" />
    <Button Content="{StaticResource ModelResource}" />
    <Button Content="{Binding}">
        <Button.DataContext>
            <wpf:Model />
        </Button.DataContext>
    </Button>
    <Button Content="{Binding}">
        <Button.DataContext>
            <wpf:Model />
        </Button.DataContext>
    </Button>
    <Button Content="{StaticResource ModelResource}" />
</StackPanel>
```

The output:

[image]